# Up button in the action bar

Tags: android, menu, navigation, android-actionbar

I have three activities as i go to second or third activity no Up button (left-facing caret alongside the app icon) showing in the those activities . I targeted for SDK 4.1 Jelly Bean.

I placed the below code in oncreate method

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

but nothing shows "Up icon" in action bar

plz suggest any code to appear UP icon in the action bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your  android:minSdkVersion="11" which could be seen in the manifest file, Up icon has been included from APK 11. For home page put getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); make sure it false and on other activities you  keep it enabled i,e "true". i have made a small sample plz try the below link which may be help you just import into your work space

http://www.mediafire.com/?hktdvts7yyduwv1

Comment: Hey @Rehan, so I have yet to add setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(), but the Up Button is already in place and is working.  Do you know what is causing this behavior?